# What do official sources say about player access to the Monster Manual?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, roll20

The [Introduction](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction) of the *Monster Manual* makes it clear several times that it is a book for DMs (MM, p. 4; emphasis mine):

> This bestiary is **for storytellers and world-builders**. If you have
> ever thought about running a DUNGEONS & DRAGONS game for your friends,
> either a single night's adventure or a long-running campaign, this
> tome contains page after page of inspiration.** [...]
>
> If you're an experienced Dungeon Master (DM)**, a few of the monster
> write-ups might surprise you, for we've gone into the *Monster
> Manuals* of yore and discovered some long-lost factoids. [...]
>
> The best thing about **being a DM** is that you get to invent your own
> fantasy world and bring it to life, and nothing brings a D&D world to
> life more than the creatures that inhabit it. [...]
>
> The *Monster Manual* is one of three books that form the foundation of
> the DUNGEONS & DRAGONS game, the other two being the *Player's
> Handbook* and the *Dungeon Master's Guide*. **The *Monster Manual*,
> like the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, is a book for DMs.**

However, it stops short of saying the *Monster Manual* is **only** for DMs, and does not specifically say that it should *not* be used by players.

---

Roll20, on the other hand, clearly made a decision to give players extensive access to information from the *Monster Manual*. Per the [Roll20 wiki page for the *Monster Manual*](https://wiki.roll20.net/Monster_Manual):

> Players can have direct access to the Monster Manual within the In-App Roll20 Compendium. You can share the Monster Manual with Compendium Sharing.

---

This is **not** a question about whether such information *should* be available to players - that is opinion-based and off-topic.

Rather, I am trying to understand:

1. Besides the statements in the MM itself, what do other official sources say about **to what extent** the information players have access to the information in the MM?
2. Did Roll20 ever *explain* their decision to provide players with full access to MM information?

While this is a list question, it is a *bounded* list - I am interested in official sources, and officially licensed sources.

It is not a 'designer's intent' question in that I am not interested in opinion, interpretation, or speculation; I am just trying to track down relevant textual quotes about who has legitimate access to the MM information, and under what circumstances.

Comment: Your Q2 is practically a designer reasons question, I recommend you delete or rewrite it. Also, could you just *not share* the statblock/handout with your players? Why would they need those info anyway?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Does a player at your table think they have a right to see the monster statblocks based on Roll20 having this option?

Comment: This is not a practical problem to resolve question.  I see it as more a research/history of gaming question - which based on my reading of meta, is allowed.  I would like to know whether other products support the MM view, and whether Roll20 explained their departure.  I don't see it as a designer intent question since I am not actually interested in the intent per se, but whether it was ever officially expressed.  I would be open to suggestions for how to rewrite this, but I would also understand votes to close from those who want the site to reflect only practical problems.

Comment: Also, my reading of the meta on why designer intent questions are no longer allowed is that it was because they too often attracted opinion-based answers.  I am hopeful that limiting my question to "does this information exist, and if so, where" will sufficiently discourage opinion-based answers.

Comment: If you would like to know about how this idea developed, then just simply ask that. I cannot guarantee that it will not be too broad (an answer would have to go through all games ever published to answer...), but you could make it answerable by placing restrictions (eg. only D&D editions).

Comment: Also, the problem with designer reasons Qs (as you said) is not asking such a Q, but how it is handled by answers. As such, how you phrase it will not absolve it, sadly.

Comment: @Zimul8r Thank you.  I am new to 5e and had not seen that.

Comment: Note that Roll20's wiki can be edited by any user. Their official help pages are now hosted on Zendesk. (The Zendesk link currently at the top of the linked wiki page doesn't seem to work, but based on the URL, the Zendesk link was on a broader topic anyway rather than being specific to the MM.)

Comment: @V2Blast I was not aware, thank you.  Although I now realize that the wiki may not represent an official statement, the fact that players in Roll20 have access to the full stat block of creatures is objectively true.

Comment: @Kirt: Correct, players can look up anything from a compendium they have access to. Though the same is true of the SRD material in any site that hosts it, to be fair; nothing prevents a player from looking up the lich statblock, for instance, whether on 5eSRD.com or Roll20 or D&D Beyond or whatever. The only difference for non-SRD material is whether the player owns it and whether/how it's shared with the group if someone else in the group owns it. (Your broader question is still valid, but I think the DM can enable/disable compendium sharing on a per-book basis as of a semi-recent update.)

Comment: (As a demonstration of the fact that Roll20's wiki is user-editable... I've now edited it to fix the typos indicated in the quote :P )

Answer (score 5):

Note that Page 304 of the *Player's Handbook* (the opening text for Appendix D) directs players to consult the *Monster Manual*. It does so for directions on how to read the stats presented in Appendix D, but that still is explicit direction for players to use the Monster Manual.

1. Yes. Specifically abilities that allow players to use monster stats. The two most common are the Druid's Wild Shape ability and the various iterations of the *polymorph* spell, though others exist.
2. Not that I am aware of. Though 1 probably played a factor.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually, The beginning for Appendix D in the PHB (p.304) says that the monster stat blocks were included in the PHB for exactly these purposes ("...allow characters to transform into animals, summon creatures to serve as familiars, and create undead."). It does not refer the players to the MM for that data. This section only recommends the MM as a reference for how to understand a stat block.

Comment: @Zimul8r Does your Appendix D include elementals? Mine does not, but a Circle of the Moon druid can turn into an elemental at level 10. Therefore, Appendix D is NOT a comprehensive list of available creatures.

Comment: Something missing is not equivalent to saying "go ahead and use the MM where you can find that." It may be obvious to do that, but OP is asking for explicit written official direction. This is not it.

Comment: What NautArch said. Also, note that many spells explicitly say [the \[DM/GM\] has the creature's statistics](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=GM&f=spells&c=spells) (DDB uses "GM" for the ones in the SRD; [*infernal calling*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infernal-calling) is the only one like that way that uses "DM" because it's a non-SRD spell from *Xanathar's*). Some other spells say [the creature's statistics are in the *Monster Manual*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=monster%20manual&f=spells&c=spells) (though this seems to be the case especially for the *Xanathar's* spells).

Comment: (It's still useful to acknowledge that there are those mentions of the *Monster Manual*, but they're also not an explicit instruction for the player to read the *Monster Manual* themselves.)

Answer (score 4):

## The *Player's Handbook* directs players to the *Monster Manual*

The [errata to the PHB](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) says, in part:

> If in doubt, the Monster Manual version of
> a creature’s stat block is authoritative.

It also says "Recent printings of the book
include revised text that reflects the explanations here", but no changes were actually made to clarify that you should look up creature stats in the MM rather than expecting the blurbs in the PHB to be 100% reliable.

Nevertheless, the PHB frequently uses 2nd person narration to make it clear its intended audience is prospective *players*, not GMs, so its errata instructing its readers to look up creatures in the MM is thusly an instruction to players as well.

It may not be an explicit instruction to look up whatever you want in the MM, but it's an instruction to consult the MM for creature stats whenever you are 'in doubt', which is basically the same thing.